# jQuery UI : Combining Selectable with Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm having a big problem trying to get my head round how the **selectable()** and **draggable()** components of jqueryUI can work together.

They work fine on their own. I am trying to create a file browser type interface that users can select multiple files or drag **INDIVIDUAL** files to other droppable places in the app. I know a lot of people have been looking at ways to drag multiple files but this is not a requirement for me at the moment.

In the example provided selectable works if using the mouse drag marquee box but no longer works for simple mouse clicks or crl click to select multiple (when draggable is enabled).

**EXAMPLE HERE:**
http://jsbin.com/aguju4/3/edit

Comment: This may be of some help, but it doesn't seem to be working in Chrome: http://nicolas.rudas.info/jquery/selectables_sortables/

Comment: Decided to scrap the selectable plugin and build a basic version myself. The two don't seem to get on very well. I have based my own selectable solution on live() clicks so that it doesn't conflict with the draggable click events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decided to scrap the selectable plugin and build a basic version myself. The two don't seem to get on very well. I have based my own selectable solution on live() clicks so that it doesn't conflict with the draggable click events.

Comment: Do you mind spreading your solution? I'm having the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue, bummed to see they don't play well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705250/is-there-a-jquery-plugin-which-combines-draggable-and-selectable

Answer (score 1):

You could have just use mousedown event to manually make the items selected.

```
var mouseDownCallback = function(e) {

    if (e.ctrlKey==0) $('#your-container').children().removeClass('ui-selected');

    $(this).addClass('ui-selected');

}
$('#your-container').on('mousedown','.item', mouseDownCallback);
```