# Error jquery-ui draggable Cannot read property 'msie'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I got some troubles to make work **jquery-ui draggable**. I will share with you my solution, this is the best solution?

I just insert this to test before I start my real work.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
  $('img').draggable();
```

Like here: http://jsbin.com/eqowet/2/

But I got a error:

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined.

Comment: you can upgrade to the newest version of jqueryui (up to 1.10.0 now)

Answer (score 34):

msie is the flag on the [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) property

[jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) was deprecated since version 1.3 and was removed in jQuery 1.9.0

Since you're using the latest version of hosted jQuery, your library was auto-upgraded to 1.9.0 hence the error.

As you've already realized, reverting back to 1.8.3 (or earlier version) fixes the issue; the  real solution, however, is to stop using [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Comment: jqueryUI is using jQuery.browser, not him

Comment: @Ascherer I just explained the root of the problem, might be helpful to others

Comment: yeah, jqueryui 1.10 doesnt use it anymore

Answer (score 5):

I try a lot of examples but all isn't working, just the same message, that I realized the version 1.8.24 isn't compatible with the last jQuery version. I have changed for it and voilà is working now.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Like here: http://jsbin.com/eqowet/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use migrate.js to get compatibility

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/

Answer (score 0):

I got this error for an older version of jquery mobile. If you are using an old JQM, you need to update. If you are on Rails you can use the jqueryhttps://github.com/tscolari/jquery-mobile-rails

If you use the rails gem right now, be sure to get the 1.3 beta 1 to get this fix:

```
gem 'jquery_mobile_rails', "~> 1.3.b1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error with "sortable".
So, make sure that all dependant scripts are included, also should be the right sequence.

```
jquery.min.js
jquery.ui.core.js
jquery.ui.sortable.min.js
```

For example to make it work on Joomla you may do like this:

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript('/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js');
$doc->addScript('/media/jui/js/jquery.ui.core.js');
$doc->addScript('/media/jui/js/jquery.ui.sortable.min.js');
```