# Is there any kind of jQuery.browser fallback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, deprecated

As jQuery.browser has been removed since 1.9 I am getting a lot of trouble because so many plugins did not get updated and still use that function despite of its absence in current jQuery releases. Is there any recommended way to modify existing plugins or any other advice?

Comment: See [Is jQuery $.browser Deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540835/jquery-browser-script-or-shim-for-backwards-compatibility-of-plugins-with-1-9-1?rq=1

Comment: I would suggest using this http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin until you can migrate over to using `$.support`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.browser() removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed):

> The `jQuery.browser()` method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and is removed in 1.9. If needed, it is available as part of the [jQuery Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/). We recommend using feature detection with a library such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/%5d)

[jQuery Migrate 1.1.1 Released](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/):

> Using the `jQuery Migrate` plugin is easy, just include it immediately after the script tag for jQuery, for example.
>
> ```
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: If you're going to quote text verbatim from somewhere else, please give a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

> jQuery.browser() removed
>
> The jQuery.browser() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and
>   is removed in 1.9. If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery
>   Migrate plugin. We recommend using feature detection with a library
>   such as Modernizr.

So it should be available here:

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/