# $.done() code gets executed before $.when()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .when

In my project I m using 2 versions of JQuery.js, so I resolved the conflict using `$.noConflict()` for my latest version of JQuery to variable named jq172. Now I have used `jq172.when().done()`construct to show loading status image until all ajax request are processed completely. The code is as follows.

```
jq172.when(
    DisplayPOXOrderStatistics(fromDate, toDate), 
    DisplayPOXCompletedOrdersData(fromDate, toDate),
    DisplayPOXCompletedOrderPieChart(fromDate, toDate),
    DisplayCurrentYearlyTrends())
      .done(function (a1,a2,a3,a4) 
        { 
           $("#loading").hide(); 
        });
```

where functions in the `jq172.when()` are coded as follows,

```
 function DisplayPOXOrderStatistics(fromDate, toDate) {        
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("DisplayPOXOrderStatistics", "Home")',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { FromDate: fromDate, ToDate: toDate },
        success: function (data) {application code.....}
    });        
}
function DisplayPOXCompletedOrdersData(fromDate, toDate) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("DisplayPOXCompletedOrders", "Home")',
        data: { FromDate: fromDate, ToDate: toDate },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { some code....}
    });
    }
```

& rest 2 functions are coded in the same way as above
Now my code in `.done()` to hide loading image dive should be executed after all 4 ajax call is finished, but currently it gets executed immediately after function call is dispatched. Can anybody figure out the problem in my code.
Thanks in Advance...

Here is the definition of rest 2 functions..

```
function DisplayPOXCompletedOrderPieChart(fromDate, toDate) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("POXCompletedOrderPieChart", "Home")',
        data: { FromDate: fromDate, ToDate: toDate },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#POXCompletedOrdersPie').empty();
            var dataSet = [];
            var isDataAvailable = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                var newElement = { label: data[i].Name, data: parseFloat(data[i].ColumnValue), color: Color[i] };
                dataSet.push(newElement);
                if (newElement.data > 0)
                    isDataAvailable = true;
            }
            if (dataSet.length != 0 && isDataAvailable) {
                $.plot($("#POXCompletedOrdersPie"), dataSet, {
                    series: {
                        pie: {
                            show: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        show: false
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#POXCompletedOrdersPie").empty();
                $("#POXCompletedOrdersPie").append("<html><p> <b>" + "@Html.Raw(VirtuOxAdvDME.Dashboard_PieChart_POXCompletedOrder_NoData)" + "</b> </p><html>");
            }
        }
    });        
}

function DisplayCurrentYearlyTrends() {
    $("#DisplayCurrentYear").html($('#selectCurrentYear option:selected').text());
    return $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("DisplayCurrentYearlyTrends", "Home")',
        data: { selectedCurrentYear: $('#selectCurrentYear option:selected').text() },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var DataValues = [], TickData = [];
            var i = undefined;
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                i = (index + 1) * 2;
                DataValues.push({ data: [i, item.Value], color: Color[i] });
                DataValues.push([i, item.Value]);
                TickData.push([i, item.MonthName]);
            });
            $.plot($("#CurrentYearlyTrendsBar"), [{ data: DataValues, color: "#3D69AA" }],
                    {
                        series: { bars: { show: true } },
                        bars: {
                            barWidth: 1.5,
                            align: "center"
                        },
                        xaxis: {
                            ticks: TickData,
                            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                            labelAngle: -90,
                        },
                        yaxis: { axisLabelUseCanvas: true },
                        grid: { hoverable: true }
                    });
            $("#CurrentYearlyTrendsBar").UseTooltip();
        }
    });        
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not keeping it simple?  I mean, you specifically want to use two versions of jquery in the same line of code?

Comment: if you use latest version of jQuery whether it is working.... like `$.when` instead of `jq172.when`

Comment: @Daedalus & Arun; Actually old version of jquery is in use from other scripts & on removing old version I m getting script errors. So I kept the both .js & resolved the conflict using var jq172=$.noConflict();

Comment: Try `jq172.ajax()` instead (though I would expect `when` to work with any promises). What is the other jQuery's version?

Comment: @Bergi, the older version I m using is 1.4.4 & later is 1.7.2. Do I need to replace all $ operators to jq172 in the current context?

Comment: @Shaggy: Not all of them, only the promise-related functions. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your `$.ajax` calls (from the old jQuery version) do not return [jqXHR objects](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) which implement the Promise interface, a feature that was introduced with v1.5. `when` would see the objects as plain values then and resolve immediately.

To fix this, use `jq172.ajax()` instead, or use a (single) up-to-date jQuery and update your legacy code.

Comment: Thans for suggestion, I switch to latest version of jquery with jquery migration script. Now I m getting $.browser is undefined error in my jquery.jqGrid.js & jquery.flot.js file; so I m searching for alternative for that. I will be thank full to you if you could suggest me something for this new problem. Then I can check out my original problem of $.when().done().

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540835/jquery-browser-script-or-shim-for-backwards-compatibility-of-plugins-with-1-9-1 for a quick'n'dirty fix, but you should avoid browser detection.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support; your solution works for me. The $.browser is undefined error was not the problem of switching to latest version of jquery as I included migration script of jquery; I was getting that error because my team mate updated the layout page of project to include script bundle of all jquery versions. I removed the script bundle & all is working fine now. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

this is from the [jquery site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

*in the multiple-Deferreds case where one of the Deferreds is rejected, jQuery.when immediately fires the failCallbacks for its master Deferred. Note that some of the Deferreds may still be unresolved at that point. If you need to perform additional processing for this case, such as canceling any unfinished ajax requests, you can keep references to the underlying jqXHR objects in a closure and inspect/cancel them in the failCallback.*

check your ajax calls and make sure no one is getting rejected.
 You can do this in the 
developers console->network tab 
generally becomes accessible after pressing F12.

Comment: Hi Parv, none of the ajax request is rejected. All are getting executed & working fine with data manupulation in sucess function.

Comment: can you please post the code for DisplayCurrentYearlyTrends() and that of DisplayPOXCompletedOrderPieChart()

Comment: Please have look at edited question for function definitions.