# Fancybox not working with jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have Fancybox working on my site, example here, scroll down to Ocean Exploration Photo Gallery:

http://www.sea.edu/academics/oe

I've added jQuery tabs to a testing version of the page, got that working, but now the FancyBox within one of the tabs isn't working. The clicked image opens up in a new window. I'm guessing the FancyBox function isn't getting activated in the tab, but can't figure out how to fix it. See example of non-working page, with the gallery in the Photo Gallery tab:

http://www.sea.edu/academics/oe_testing

Here is the function that works on other pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel=fancygallery]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

I've changed the "_testing" page to remove references to different versions of the jQuery library, which didn't fix the problem. After some searching around, I tried changing to this, still no luck:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#OEtabs-3").each(function() {
    $("a[rel=fancygallery]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the deprecated jQuery.browser msie property which is used by `fancybox 1.3.4` (see also [Error jquery-ui draggable Cannot read property 'msie'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366322/error-jquery-ui-draggable-cannot-read-property-msie))
So you have to downgrade to `jQuery 1.8.3` or better use the new `fancybox 2` (but be aware of the noncommercial licence here).

See small demo with `jQuery 1.8.3` and `fancybox 1.3.4` here: http://jsfiddle.net/JUtz2/
and the version with `jQuery 1.9.1` and `fancybox 2.1.4` here: http://jsfiddle.net/M9jUm/1/

Comment: @Lauren : more about the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987 the post includes possible workarounds and/or the fancybox v1.3.4 patched file that works with jQuery v1.9+