# Elements became randomly non-resizable after dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

After multiple elemens are selected and dragged, some of them are no more resizable: resize icon disappear from right corner.

Resizable icon remains in old place and does not move which moved elements.

To reproduce, run code below, select all elements using lasso and drag selected elements. After that resize icon disappers from random elements and those elements are no more draggable.

How to fix this ?

i tried to fix this by adding

```
$(".designer-verticalline, .designer-rectangle, .designer-field, .designer-image").resizable();
```

to end of drag() methos but problem persists

Reported also in

https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/14898#ticket

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/txbcj9qy/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
    .designer-panel-body {
      min-height: 1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .panel-footer {
      background-color: inherit;
    }
    .designer-panel,
    .designer-resetmargins {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .designer-verticalline,
    .designer-horizontalline,
    .designer-rectangle {
      font-size: 1pt;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
    .designer-field {
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
      white-space: pre;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .ui-selecting {
      background-color: lightskyblue;
      color: white;
    }
    .ui-selected {
      background-color: lightskyblue;
      border-color: darkblue;
      color: white;
    }
    .designer-label {
      white-space: pre;
      /*overflow: hidden;*/
    }
    .designer-field,
    .designer-label {
      font-family: "Times New Roman";
      font-size: 10pt;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    .designer-verticalline,
    .designer-horizontalline,
    .designer-rectangle,
    .designer-field,
    .designer-image,
    .designer-label {
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
    function getpos(e) {
      return {
        X: e.pageX,
        Y: e.pageY
      };
    }

    function Rect(start, stop) {
      this.left = Math.min(start.X, stop.X);
      this.top = Math.min(start.Y, stop.Y);
      this.width = Math.abs(stop.X - start.X);
      this.height = Math.abs(stop.Y - start.Y);
    }

    $(function() {
      var startpos;
      var selected = $([]),
        offset = {
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        };
      $(".designer-verticalline, .designer-rectangle, .designer-field, .designer-image").resizable();

      // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705250/is-there-a-jquery-plugin-which-combines-draggable-and-selectable#8643716
      // teha: seal on ka mousedown mis andis viga, kaseda kasutada
      var $liigutatavad = $(".designer-verticalline, .designer-horizontalline, .designer-rectangle, .designer-field, .designer-image, .designer-label");
      $liigutatavad.draggable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
          var $this = $(this);

          if ($this.hasClass("ui-selected")) {
            // if this is selected, attach current offset
            // of each selected element to that element
            selected = $(".ui-selected").each(function() {
              var el = $(this);
              el.data("offset", el.offset());
            });
          } else {
            // if this is not selected, clear current selection
            selected = $([]);
            $liigutatavad.removeClass("ui-selected");
          }
          offset = $this.offset();
        },

        drag: function(event, ui) {
          // drag all selected elements simultaneously
          var dt = ui.position.top - offset.top,
            dl = ui.position.left - offset.left;
          selected.not(this).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var elOffset = $this.data("offset");
            $this.css({
              top: elOffset.top + dt,
              left: elOffset.left + dl
            });
          });

          // this does not fix the issue:
          //$(".designer-verticalline, .designer-rectangle, .designer-field, .designer-image").resizable();
        }
      });

      // ...but manually implement selection to prevent interference from draggable()
      $(".designer-panel-body").on("click", "div", function(e) {
        if ( /*!e.metaKey &&*/ !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey) {
          // deselect other elements if meta/shift not held down
          $(".designer-panel-body").removeClass("ui-selected");
          $(this).addClass("ui-selected");
        } else {
          if ($(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
          } else {
            $(this).addClass("ui-selected");
          }
        }

        //var selectable = $("#container").data("selectable");
        //selectable.refresh();
        //$( ".designer-panel-body" ).data("selectable")._mouseStop(null);
      });

      $(".designer-panel-body").selectable({});
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class='panel designer-panel'>
    <div class='panel-body designer-panel-body panel-warning' style='height:9.37cm'>

      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:2.30cm;left:5.84cm;width:10.24cm;height:0.63cm;font-family:Arial;font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold;'>vnimi+&#39; &#39;+dok.tasudok</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:2.30cm;left:16.37cm;width:2.68cm;height:0.61cm;font-size:14pt;'>DOK.kuupaev</div>
      <div class='rectangle' style='border-width: 1px;background-color:#FFFFFF;top:2.99cm;left:1.34cm;width:18.05cm;height:5.29cm'></div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:3.01cm;left:1.53cm;width:9.71cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>m.FIRMA</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:3.01cm;left:12.13cm;width:3.13cm;height:0.53cm;font-size:12pt;'>ise.telefon</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:3.01cm;left:17.11cm;width:1.89cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;text-align:right;'>ise.regnr</div>
      <div class='designer-label' contenteditable='true' style='top:3.04cm;left:11.39cm;text-align:right;font-size:12pt;'>Tel.</div>
      <div class='designer-label' contenteditable='true' style='top:3.04cm;left:15.71cm;font-size:12pt;'>Reg.Nr</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:3.62cm;left:1.55cm;width:9.45cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>ise.tanav</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:3.70cm;left:15.16cm;width:3.37cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>ise.vatpayno</div>
      <div class='designer-label' contenteditable='true' style='top:3.72cm;left:12.89cm;text-align:right;font-size:12pt;'>KMKR nr</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:4.30cm;left:1.58cm;width:9.08cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>rtri(ise.postiindek)+&#39; &#39;+rtri(ise.piirkond)</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:4.30cm;left:14.66cm;width:4.34cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;text-align:right;'>aarve(dok.arvekonto, &#39;konto.arveldusar&#39;)</div>
      <div class='designer-label' contenteditable='true' style='top:4.33cm;left:13.89cm;font-size:12pt;'>A/A</div>
      <div class='designer-horizontalline' style='border-width: 1px;top:4.96cm;left:1.34cm;width:18.03cm;height:0.00cm'></div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:5.04cm;left:17.13cm;width:1.89cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;text-align:right;'>klient.regnr</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:5.06cm;left:4.18cm;width:12.71cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>klient.nimi</div>
      <div class='designer-label' contenteditable='true' style='top:5.06cm;left:15.74cm;font-size:12pt;'>Reg.Nr</div>
      <div class='designer-label' contenteditable='true' style='top:5.09cm;left:1.63cm;font-size:12pt;'>Maksja</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:5.72cm;left:1.53cm;width:11.68cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>klient.tanav</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:5.72cm;left:15.18cm;width:3.37cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>klient.vatpayno</div>
      <div class='designer-label' contenteditable='true' style='top:5.75cm;left:12.92cm;text-align:right;font-size:12pt;'>KMKR nr</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:6.38cm;left:1.53cm;width:11.84cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>rtri(klient.postiindek)+&#39; &#39; +rtri(klient.piirkond)</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:6.38cm;left:13.47cm;width:3.37cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>sql(&quot;sele transfld(&#39;nimetus&#39;, &#39;riik&#39;, rapopref()) from riik where kood=klient.riik2&quot;, &#39;&#39; )</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:6.99cm;left:3.71cm;width:12.16cm;height:1.16cm;font-size:12pt;'>klient.aadress</div>
      <div class='designer-label' contenteditable='true' style='top:7.01cm;left:1.45cm;text-align:right;font-size:12pt;'>Postiaadress</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:8.33cm;left:3.95cm;width:2.11cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>dok.tasukuup</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:8.33cm;left:6.08cm;width:8.05cm;height:0.55cm;font-size:12pt;'>eval( &#39;maksetin.&#39; +left(rapopref()+&#39;tingimus&#39;,10))</div>
      <div class='designer-label' contenteditable='true' style='top:8.35cm;left:1.45cm;font-size:12pt;'>Makset&#228;htaeg</div>
      <div class='designer-field' contenteditable='true' style='top:8.91cm;left:1.45cm;width:13.66cm;height:0.45cm;'>iif(!empty(dok.saaja), IR(&quot;Saaja: &quot;)+sql(&#39;sele rtri(nimi)+&quot; &quot;+rtri(tanav)+&quot; &quot;+rtri(piirkond)+&quot; &quot;+rtri(postiindek) from klient where kood=dok.saaja&#39;,&#39;&#39;),&#39;&#39;)</div>
    </div>
    <div class='bg-warning'>
      <div class='panel-footer'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></i> GroupHeader 1: str(dokumnr)+str(koopia,2)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the resizable icons are selectable as well, so when you include them in the lasso, they are selected and their `top` and `left` are changed when you drag.

`Selectable` has a `filter option` that allows to specify which elements should be selectable. By setting it to `'.designer-field'` it should solve the problem.

```
$(".designer-panel-body").selectable({
    filter: '.designer-field'
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/kec4jgvf/1/